# Opening all PDF links in new window (using jQuery) not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pdf

I am coding a website for a client using Wordpress as the CMS. I put this code into the header.php of my Wordpress site. It is not working though when I test it on the website. I checked the page source, and the code is there. So I have no idea why the PDF links are still opening in the current window and not a new one. Any thoughts on this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('target', '_blank');  
 });
</script>
```

Comment: What you have should work - assuming that the `a` elements are present in the DOM when the page loads. If they are loaded dynamically (via AJAX for example) then you would need to use a delegated event handler.

Comment: And it has jQuery loaded?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is loading on the page. @RoryMcCrossan This may be the issue. How do I know if they're being loaded in dynamically? And if they are, do you have an idea of what I would put for an event handler? Thanks